# loop knowledge inquiry in Java

Tags: java, loops

please see code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int j = x - i;
        if (j % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + ",j:" + j);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it only prints i:4,j:3, but I think there should be i:1,j:6 in addition.

Answer (score 7):

```
i++;
```

You're incrementing `i` twice in every iteration, which means that `i` only ever has even values.

Comment: Thanks mate, does it mean as there is a "i++" in else condition,so when it loops back to i, it will always incrementing as +2, so it takes value only 0,2 and 4 for i

Answer (score 0):

It will never print i=6, since i takes values between 0 and 4. Regarding j, it takes  from 7 to 3.

It would be better if you just say want you want to accomplish, and we go from there.

BTW, you should consider following best practices. This code is seriously ugly.

Comment: Thanks mate, does it mean as there is a "i++" in else condition,so when it loops back to i, it will always incrementing as +2, so it takes value only 0,2 and 4 for i

Comment: and btw, I said i:1, not 6